# Selecting * from 2 Tables without any similar row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new at Programming, so I have a question about selecting a data in MySQL. All the answer is about merging and joining that I'm not really looking for. returns

First table containing all the user data, and second table showing all posts by users.

I've tried doing this:

```
$sql="select * from wall, maintable where postverification="yes" AND userid='".$_SESSION['userid']."'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

The reason I want to get these different data is so i can post to php a hidden field in the form that containing "who post what" in the same page called wall.php (Like a twitter concept, but the timeline showing all user post)

The code that i've tried above only selecting from 1 table whether "wall" or "maintable".

Why is this happening?

Comment: What's your tables structure? Also mysql_* functions are (being?) depreciated, you should switch to using mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: Based on the information you provide about the two tables, they almost MUST have a common column - containing the user ID or similar. Join the tables on that column and then use a normal join. You might [get some benefit from reading this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) that I put together to help with questions like this.

Comment: Hello @TomHart Thankyou for your response. I'm trying to understand your question, my maintable contain userid, fullname, nickname. and my wall table contain postid postverification fullpost and title. is it you asking?

Comment: You need to change the structure of your table.Your `wall table` must have an  `userid` which meaningfully connects it with `main table`.

Comment: @user3665072: TomHart is not asking, he is telling you. You say that the second table contains posts from *users*. So users and posts *are* related. Only your wall table doesn't show that relation. How do you know who posted? Is there maybe a third table holding that relation?

Comment: BTW: maintable is not a good name for a table. A table name should tell what the table contains.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner krishna Yep I've just realized that they're related. But from what I've Known before (from just 2 days learning), if i put things like "Select * from maintable, wall where userid" it will selecting only  the post that posted by the userid isn't it? Sorry, beginner here :D

Comment: @user3665072 - it would select all the rows from the table with a column called userid which has the value you specify, but combined with EVERY row from the other table. So it maintable contained 10 posts for (say) userid = 5, and wall had 100 rows, you would bring back 500 rows. This is why you specify a column to join the 2 tables on (ie, a column where the values match when one tables row relates to the other tables row).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner okay i've changed my maintable name with userprofile, thankyou thorsten :D

Comment: @user3665072: Can you explain exactly what you want to see in your result list? Which rows? All user-wall combinations? Or one record per user? Or one record per wall? And what columns do you want to show?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner sure thorsten, why not haha. My purpose is to show in the wall.php containing : All posts and the nickname who post it each and the form to post under it posting to "postprocess.php". The problem here is, i have to select  the nickname that indexed by the userid. and the wall i want to be shown is all post (the post, indexed by postid)

Comment: Guys, thankyou for helping me. you just help a 12 years old who get influenced by learntocode campaign and start to learn code using an used old book that using an indonesian language, so using a very advanced term is kinda hard for me. 

this is what i did:

    select * from userprofile, wall where userid='".$_SESSION['userid']."'

(i've changed the maintable to userprofile based on thorsten advice. thankyou thorsten!)

But thankyou for helping me. Goodluck GBU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you look for something like this:

```
SELECT a.field1, b.field2 FROM table1 AS a, table2 AS b WHERE a.field3=b.field3
```

Or using LEFT JOIN,the same query becomes:

```
SELECT a.field1, b.field2 
FROM table1 AS a
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON a.field3=b.field3
```

You need to look at sql aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)  statement:

```
select * from wall inner join nmaintable on wall.'samefield'=postverification.'samefield'
 where postverification="yes" AND userid='".$_SESSION['userid']."'";
```

Also consider SQL [injection](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sql-injection.htm), try using [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo_mysql).